# Can anybody tell me how the "scanf" function works?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str(100);
    int i;

    printf("Please enter your name")
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("your name");

    return 0 ;
}
```

This is the code I have written,
but the problem is the code runs but never gives the output
until I manually stop the code.
How does the scanf("") function work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please read the documentation instead. If you have any specific question then come back and ask here. But this is considered too broad to be answered here. This could help [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: You are assuming that the `scanf` function is wrong here. It isn't. Your line `char str(100);` is wrong, and your code does not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanf reads formatted input from the standard input. There is nothing wrong with scanf itself. Your way of using it is also correct, but there are two problems with your code:

The first is that arrays must be defined with `[]`. Therefore,

```
char str(100);
```

should be

```
char str[100];
```

The second problem is that you are receiving the input, but you are never printing it. To do so, you can write the following code:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

The final code being:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Please enter your name");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("your name is: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, don't forget the semi-colons.